# Messages not rolling back on K8s pod restarts when using Spring JMS Listener with Client Ack

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We have Spring JMS application ( deployed on K8s) which processes about 100 - 400 messages/sec. The application consumes messages from IBM MQ and processes them. Off late we have started noticing messages getting dropped whenever K8s pod restarts or deployments are done even though we have message ack in place. I am looking for a solution here to resolve this issue.

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Spring Boot | 2.1.7.RELEASE |
| IBM MQ Client | 9.1.0.5 |
| JMS | 2.0.1 |
| Java | 11 |

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MqConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(Servers configProperties) {
        MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        try {
            mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(configProperties.getHost());
            mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(configProperties.getQueueManager());
            mqConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(configProperties.getPort()));
            mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(configProperties.getChannel());
            mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logError(mqConnectionFactory, ,
                    "Failed to create MQ ConnectionFactory", String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST), e);
        }
        return mqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory provideJmsListenerContainerFactory(
            MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(Throwable t) {
                ServiceMetrics metrics = new ServiceMetrics();
                metrics.setCorrelationId(UUID.getUUID());
                logger.logError(factory, "Exception occured at JMS Factory Container Listener", String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST), t);
            }
        });
        
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsQueueTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate provideJmsQueueTemplate(MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Servers configProperties;


    @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public ExecutorService getAsyncTaskExecutor() {
        String THREAD_POOL = "th-pool-";
        return getExecutor(THREAD_POOL, 70,true);
    }

    private ExecutorService getExecutor(String threadName, int maxPoolSize, boolean cached) {
        final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new CustomizableThreadFactory(threadName);
        if (cached) {
            ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxPoolSize,
                    60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), threadFactory);
            threadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, executor) -> {
                if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                    try {
                        executor.getQueue().put(r);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RejectedExecutionException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            return threadPoolExecutor;
        } else {

            return new ThreadPoolExecutor(maxPoolSize, maxPoolSize,
                    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(),
                    threadFactory);
        }
    }
```

```
@Component
public class InputQueueListener {

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService asyncTaskExecutor;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${mqserver.queue}", containerFactory = "messageListenerContainerFactory", concurrency = "1-16")
    public void processXMLMessage(Message message)  {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processMessage(message), asyncTaskExecutor);
    }

    private void processMessage(Message message) {
        String inputXmlMessage = null;
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                inputXmlMessage = textMessage.getText();
            } else if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
                BytesMessage byteMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
                inputXmlMessage = CommonHelperUtil.getMessageFromBytes(byteMessage);
            } else {
                logger.logError(null, "Invalid message type received while converting Message to XML", String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST));
                errorQueuePublisher.publishErrorMessage(message);
                try {
                    message.acknowledge();
                } catch (JMSException jmsException) {
                    logger.logError(null, null, "Failed to Acknowledge XML message.",
                            String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST), jmsException);
                }
            }
            -
            -

            if (isSuccessProcessed) {
                message.acknowledge();
                
            } else {
                
                message.acknowledge();
                // Publishing back to the same queue
                publishForRetry.publishMessageForRetry(message);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(serviceMetrics.getCorrelationId())) {
                serviceMetrics.setCorrelationId(UUID.getUUID());
            }

            logger.logError(null, null, "Exception while Converting Processing Message. Retrying to publish.",
                        String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST), e);
                // Publishing back to the same queue
                publishForRetry.publishMessageForRetry(message);
                try {
                    message.acknowledge();
                } catch (JMSException jmsException) {
                    logger.logError(null, null,
                            "Failed to Acknowledge the Message when publishing" + "to Error Queue",
                            String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST), jmsException);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the messages you are consuming persistent?

Comment: Yes they are persistent @JoshMc

Comment: If `message.acknowledge()` is not called before you restart then the message should be rolled back to the queue once MQ notices you are disconnected.  Is your app ending gracefully or just getting killed,  if gracefully you should issue a specific rollback for any outstanding messages,  in some cases a graceful disconnect from MQ will issue a implied commit.

Comment: We are in a position where K8s is killing the pod. So I am assuming this is not a graceful disconnection

Comment: Do you see entries in the queue manager log indicating the SVRCONN channel ended abnormally?  If you don't then it is likely graceful.

Comment: I have modified the code by adding sessionTransacted in addition to Client Ack as session ack mode. The message is getting rolled back but on restart although the message is available in the queue, the application is not able to consume it. Not sure if I am missing something here 
factory.setSessionTransacted(true);

Comment: Transacted sessions do not use ack, they use commit.   The ack mode is ignored for transacted sessions. There is even a value for this `SESSION_TRANSACTED`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but I do not think it addresses my issue. My original code ran with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and when k8s terminates my service before the client acknowledges the message the message is lost. Adding sessionTransacted(true) resulted in the message not being lost (it reappeared in the queue) but it was not accessible when the service restarted.

Comment: Does the qmgr still think you are connected?